# TypeError: data.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a Position of price located on Ebay Store "https://www.ebay.com/itm/352982099966?var=622208604310" but I got This error:
TypeError: data.getBoundingClientRect is not a function .

What I Tried :

```
        const response = await axios({
        url:"https://www.ebay.com/itm/352982099966?var=622208604310",
         })
    const document = parse(response.data)

    var data = document.querySelector('span[id="prcIsum"]')
    var rect = data.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = rect.left;
    y = rect.top;
    w = rect.width;
    h = rect.height;
    console.log(x,y,w,h)
```

when I tried this code on browser's console , it gives me a required result by adding this same code.

```
        var data = document.querySelector('span[id="prcIsum"]')
    var rect = data.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = rect.left;
    y = rect.top;
    w = rect.width;
    h = rect.height;
    console.log(x,y,w,h)
```

But when I tried in my code , it gives me error[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr2pR.png)

Comment: They're not rendered. There is no window. The `span` doesn't really have a position.

Comment: To clarify, that is in Node.js. `parse(response.data)` doesn't actually run a browser or a rendering engine to render your HTML, it only parses it, meaning the `span` or any other element don't have a position.

Comment: Then , what is the alternate to get position of any tags

Comment: It is impossible to get the size and position of the element without actually rendering the page (using some kind of browser environment). The code may *run* with libraries like jsdom, but iirc jsdom does not handle rendering and simply return `0` for all dimensions.